# Rotating a pie chart

Tags: datatool, charts

How can I rotate  a pie chart with 50,50 distribution so that it is divided vertically rather than horizontally?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{datapie}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{filecontents}{institutes.csv}
Name,Quantity
"ERD", 50
"NERD",50
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{population.csv}
Name,Quantity
"ERD", 30
"NERD", 70
\end{filecontents}

\DTLloaddb{institute}{institutes.csv}
\DTLloaddb{population}{population.csv}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Are all the gastroesophageal reflux disease patients same? }
\begin{exampleblock}
{All patients present with  heart burn \texttt{and/or} regurgitation of sour fluid in mouth }So all these patients are same with varying severity of symptoms?
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{itemize}
\item upper gastro-intestinal endoscopy 
\item 24 hour Ph-metry 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Endoscopy Data}
\begin{columns}{2}
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity,outerlabel=\name}{institute}{%
\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}
\caption{Institute data} 
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity,outerlabel=\name}{population}{%
\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}
\caption{Population data}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the starting angle of the first segment by the setting `start=90`. The value is 0 by default.

```
    \DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity,outerlabel=\name,start=90,radius=1.8cm,outerratio=1.1}{institute}{%
\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}
```

I have made some other changes too in the settings so that the chart looks more good.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{datapie}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{filecontents}{institutes.csv}
Name,Quantity
"ERD", 50
"NERD",50
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{population.csv}
Name,Quantity
"ERD", 30
"NERD", 70
\end{filecontents}

\DTLloaddb{institute}{institutes.csv}
\DTLloaddb{population}{population.csv}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Are all the gastroesophageal reflux disease patients same? }
\begin{exampleblock}
{All patients present with  heart burn \texttt{and/or} regurgitation of sour fluid in mouth }So all these patients are same with varying severity of symptoms?
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{itemize}
\item upper gastro-intestinal endoscopy
\item 24 hour Ph-metry
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Endoscopy Data}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity,outerlabel=\name,start=90,radius=1.8cm,outerratio=1.1}{institute}{%
\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}
\caption{Institute data}
\end{figure}
\end{column}%
\hfill
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity,outerlabel=\name,start=90,radius=1.8cm,outerratio=1.1}{population}{%
\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}
\caption{Population data}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]